# data_format in JAX/FLAX

Tags: jax, flax

I did not find any settings for `data_format=channels_first` or `data_format=channels_last` in FLAX modules ( which are based on JAX ).

On the contrary, TensorFlow does have that designation. Does the choice of data_format is irrelevant to JAX performance ?

Unfortunately, I did not find any kind of information on this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAX/Flax has no equivalent to the concept of `data_format` as used in Tensorflow/Keras.

Comment: Does it mean that the data_format has no bearing upon the runtime efficiency ?